# Dynamic Linq accessing columns

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, datatable, datarow, dynamic-linq

I have been trying to create a dynamic query that will check the contents of a datatable.
The thing is I the number columns to be selected and also there names are given at runtime.
The where clause thus needs to be constructed dynamically.
Is there any way to do this in Dynamic linq?

I started with a small eg

```
string query = "Field<string>(@0)=@1";
            fsrch = GetValues();
var result = CapacityTable.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().Where(query);
```

I also tried

```
            var result = CapacityTable.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().Where("Location = @1","Chennai");
```

In both cases I get an error saying DataRow does not have the specified property. How do I access the columns of the table dynamically????

Comment: You *are* using the dynamic linq library, or you put the `dynamic-linq` tag because it had the words `dynamic` and `linq`?

Comment: I am using dynamic linq library

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) blog written by Scott Gu.